# TS003: Error, TS001: Please go to Tools->Azure Services Authentication, and re-authenticate the account you want to use

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-active-directory

Got following exception (on `GetSecretAsync` call):

> 'TS003: Error, TS001: This account 'XXXXXXX' needs re-authentication. Please go to Tools->Azure Services Authentication, and re-authenticate the account you want to use.

when using standard Azure auth code from [How to use managed identities...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet)

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
      azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
var secret = await 
kv.GetSecretAsync("https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret");
```

Could not find "`Tools->Azure Services Authentication`" anywhere in VS 2019...

There are some similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57678993/exception-while-connecting-to-keyvault-from-azure-vm) but none tells if that tool is anywhere in VS 2019.

Answer (score 9):

Turned out that this menu moved to Tools->Options - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4091

> Tools->Options->Azure Services Authentication

If you could not find the option in your Visual Studio make sure "Azure Development" workload is installed by launching Visual Studio Installer and then selecting "Modify" for VS 2019.

Note that if you have VS configured to break on all exceptions the exception may happen even if everything is fine and it gets handled internally with `GetSecretAsync` successfully finishing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS Code, you can install the Azure Account extension. Once the extension is installed, press F1 to open the command palette and run the Azure: Sign In command.